# How to Filtering List of Objects using LINQ and Return from a Function

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to filter a list of Chord objects (class) in C# using linq.

I have the following function in my class

```
public List<Chord> FilterDictionary_byKey<Chord>(string theKey)
{
    var filteredList = from item in _chords
                       where item.KeyName == theKey
                       select item;

    return (List<Chord>)filteredList;
}
```

in the above Chord is an object type, _chords is a class variable of List type.

then from my calling code I tried the following:

```
List<Chord> theChords = globalVariables.chordDictionary.FilterDictionary_byKey("A");
```

obviously trying to return a filtered list of Chord objects from the class

however, when i compile the compiler returns

Error   1   The type arguments for method 'ChordDictionary.chordDictionary.FilterDictionary_byKey(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  C:\Users\Daniel\Development\Projects\Tab Explorer\Tab Explorer\Forms\ScaleAndChordViewer.cs 75  37  Tab Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inferred type of a `from`…`select` LINQ query is actually an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is not a populated list or collection, but a sequence that will be enumerated on demand. Casting it to `List<T>` does not cause this enumeration; instead, you should call `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

To address the error you’re getting: Your method declaration should not have a generic type parameter, since neither its return type nor any of its parameters are generic. Just remove the `<Chord>` following the method name.

```
public List<Chord> FilterDictionary_byKey(string theKey)
{
    var filteredList = from item in _chords
                       where item.KeyName == theKey
                       select item;

    return filteredList.ToList();
}
```

Comment: But also consider if your method could as well be `public IEnumerable<Chord> FilterDictionary_byKey(string theKey)`, that is have return type `IEnumerable<>`. Then return the `filteredList` directly, and the query will only be enumerated when needed. Calling `ToList()` will enumerate the query immediately which may be good or bad depending on how you use the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Chord> theChords = globalVariables.chordDictionary.FilterDictionary_byKey<Chord>("A");
```

Comment: -1: This code would solve the issue if the called method actually had a generic type parameter, which it does not. (The OP specified that `Chord` is a class.) The error lies in the method declaration, not its invocation.